# How can I get the real pivot position of a node with assimp?

Tags: unity-game-engine, maya, assimp

How to use assimp to obtain the real position of the pivot point.

The position I got is the same with Maya Channel Box, but I want to know the true location of the pivot point when it has been changed with the key [D] in Maya or the transform has been frozen.

The node position should be the same with Transform Component in unity.

Thanks!

Comment: I think that `transform.localPosition` should get the local pivot point. I am not entirely sure but try this.

Answer (score 1):

you could add the xform rotatepivot and xform translation :

```
import maya.cmds as mc

obj = 'pCube1'
rotatepivot = mc.xform(obj, q=1, rotatePivot=True)
transformPivot = mc.xform(obj, q=1, translation=True)

truePivot = [x+y for x,y in zip(rotatepivot,transformPivot)]
```